# R - how to load a package (plugin) with Rscript during execution from a a command line?

Tags: r, windows, session, command

How to load package with Rscript when I execute a call to RScript from a command line?

This is the packag (plugin) I have when open regular R session:

[image]

I need to load `FactSet3_3.0` package (plugin) during a command call to Rscript.
How to specify that in command line as a parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: Put `library(FactSet3)` in your Rscript file.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks, tried and is is saying `there is no package called "FactSet3"`. What is the way to see all available packages (and namespaces) when running a script (so that I can see the exact name)?

Comment: Are you running on a different computer? A different version of R? Running `installed.packages()` will list all the packages available to R in a given session.

Comment: yeah, that was a change that is needed..